# Webview with buttons on the bottom of the view

Tags: android, button, webview

I have went through countless examples of webview with buttons and can't get any of them to show my buttons.

Below is my last layout and it looks correct in eclipse but the website goes full screen when run on the phone.

[image]

Any help would be great!

Kind Regards,

Mike

Comment: Tried using frames didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a parent element to encompass the two separate child elements WebView and LinearLayout

have a go with the resources on Android Developers: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html

It should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/webview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="380px"
/>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal" 
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it does look like that not sure why my full code didn't come through.  You code didn't work either.  Same issue website takes up full view.

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Answer (score 2):

If this is something you actually have in your code it's not even valid XML since you don't seem to have a common outer tag. This should be something like the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_height="0" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/back" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Back" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/next" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

P.S. I'm modyfying my answer based on the additional information. Your problem is that when you load page into WebView it breaks out into stand-alone browser.
To deal with this problem simply add custom WebViewClient to your WebView which simply overrides `WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method. Something like this:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });
```

Comment: not sure why my code didn't come through it has the common outer tag. still no luck.

Comment: And you don't need to specify namespace in any nested elements. To fix your code all you need to do is to change height of your webview to 0dip then set layout weight of the webview to be 1. Otherwise your webvie is pushing your buttons off the screen

Comment: BTW setting your WebView to fixed height is definitely bad idea since you can't support different resolutions that way